# Solving ln/exponent question

Tags: logarithms

How do I change the subject of the equation from x to y in the following equation:

$$x=[4.105-\ln(\sqrt{y})]^2$$

Comment: Exponentiate rhs and lhs, may be !

Comment: why did you remove your work? Leave it, it shows your effort...

Comment: Because when I did my own work I did not notice there was a - (minus sign) which makes everything completely wrong

Comment: come on you can even do that in a minute...I believe in you...

Comment: I think it is y^1/2=e^(x^(1/2)-4.105) but then there should be two results, a positive and a negative shouldn't it?

Comment: Correct, after a certain period, you can even post your own answer to your question. BTW: Welcome to MSE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x=[4.105-\ln(\sqrt{y})]^2 \Rightarrow \pm\sqrt{x}=4.105-\ln(\sqrt{y}) \Rightarrow \pm\sqrt{x}=4.105-\ln({y}^{\frac{1}{2}}) \Rightarrow \\ \pm\sqrt{x}=4.105-\frac{1}{2}\ln({y}) \Rightarrow \ln{(y)}=2 \cdot 4.105\pm2 \sqrt{x} \Rightarrow y=e^{2 \cdot 4.105\pm2 \sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since this is where you got stuck previously, here is my

**HINT**: What is the inverse function to $\ln$?

> $$\exp(\ln(f(x)))=f(x)$$